# How to set up partitions for 3 OS's

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I currently run Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 on my 500GB hard drive. I use grub2 to choose which one to boot to each time. The partition layout looks this:

- Linux: 100GB
- Linux Swap: 16GB
- Windows System Reserve: 100MB <-- no clue what this is
- Windows 7: 100GB

I would like to install another Linux partition on here, but I can only have 4 partitions. I have heard that you can have extended partitions that hold more partitions. The problem is that I cannot create another extended partition because I have 4 vital partitions already. I do not know how grub2 works with extended partitions as well. How should I proceed from here? What should my partition layout look like and how should I get to that?

Comment: `Easeus partition manager` or `Minitool partition wizard` will do the job for you, I don't remember exactly if they are for linux but sure that they are available for windows.

Comment: If your computer supports [EFI,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uefi) you can use that and the [GUID Partition Table (GPT),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) which has a default limit of 128 partitions, not 4. Most computers sold since mid-2011 support EFI, as do some older models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) (the LiveCD/LiveUSB version recommended) to repartition.
- GRUB can handle extended partitions just fine (there might be BIOS limitations but probably not).
- 16GB of swap is fairly excessive, how much RAM does your system have?

**Current layout:**

```
/dev/sda1     100GB    Ubuntu
/dev/sda2      16GB    linux-swap
/dev/sda3     100MB    Windows bootloader
/dev/sda4     100GB    Win7
unallocated  ~272GB
```

**Proposed layout:**

```
/dev/sda1     100GB    Ubuntu
/dev/sda2     100MB    Win boot
/dev/sda3     100GB    Win7
/dev/sda4    ~288GB    extended
/dev/sda5    ~284GB    new partition
/dev/sda6       4GB    linux-swap
```

**Steps:**

1. Delete **/dev/sda2** (the swap partition)
2. Resize/Move **/dev/sda3** (Win boot), set the *"Free space proceeding (MiB):"* to **0**
3. Resize/Move **/dev/sda4** (Win7), set the *"Free space proceeding (MiB):"* to **0**
4. New *extended partition* from the **~288GB unallocated space** at the end of the drive
5. New *logical partition*, size **~284GB**, file system: **EXT4**, label: **MyNewPartition**
6. New *logical partition*, size **4GB**, file system: **linux-swap**
7. Apply all operations (you may want to do this for each step individually but note the partition numbers may change)
8. Change the UUID for the swap partition in Ubuntu's `/etc/fstab`

*Warning: it's perfectly safe to delete the swap partition, however, any partitioning operation **especially** moving/resizing partitions is inherently risky.*

Comment: Or run without a swap partition at all, and set up linux to use swap files.